# Are empty arrays no longer allowed by gcc?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, initialization

I have gcc 4.7.2-3 and I get this following error:

main.c:5:6: error: array size missing in ‘fname’

main.c:6:6: error: array size missing in ‘lname’

when initializing this:

```
int fname[];
int lname[];
```

Is this no longer possible using higher versions of gcc? Because I am certain I have used this before...

EDIT: The reason I say I remember this, is because I even see it here:
http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_046.HTM

Comment: What is an "empty array"? The compiler is just telling you that you declare an array without a size. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only declare an array with no size if you are initializing it right away

```
int myarr[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

or if it is the last member in a structure

```
struct foo {
  int something;
  int somethingelse;
  char emptyarr[];
};
```

Comment: Nevermind, I see the error in my ways.
Even in my own link "Note that the specified size of the array does not matter in the case of a function parameter".
Which I do know about the function parameter, and as I think back I have used your first example by initializing it right away.

Comment: @Archxiao: In fact a function parameter that looks like it's of array type is really of pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

Array of zero length can be either a [GNU C extension or a flexible array member](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) introduced in C99 (which C++ compilers also happen to support and I am not sure if it is in C++ standard or not). In either case, those are allowed as a last member of a structure only and otherwise are not allowed and do not make any sense either.

The document that you refer to does use or show "empty" arrays. You are confusing [array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) for "empty" arrays.

Comment: `do not make any sense either` - empty arrays very much make sense when testing API's with various data and buffer sizes, wanting to also verify your API with the empty case. I'm not sure about C, but in C++, the work-around is to say `std::array<float, 0> emptyArray; MyApiToTest(std::data(emptyArray), std::size(emptyArray));` since `float emptyArray[] = {};` doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it was ever possible in any compiler, array size must be known at compile time. You were probably doing initialization right away:

```
int fname[] = { 1, 2, 3};
```

This way compiler can derive the size.

EDIT: Ah, missed the "C" tag. :) It seems to be illegal in C++ though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare an array with 0 size. To do so you need to declare as mentioned below

```
int array[] = {};
```

For example

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={};
    printf("size = %d", sizeof(a));
    return 1;
}
```

`./a.out` gives you 0 as output.